# Looking for simple and lightweight plugin for post reading stats

Tags: statistics, plugin-recommendation

I am already using Piwik to register all stats of my blog site. What I need now is a simple and lightweight plugin that stores the number of visitors for single posts.

It would be nice if it provides a way to show the number of readings inside the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want [wp-postviews](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-postviews/)

Answer (score 1):

Well, the mother of all analytics solutions is [google analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics). There's a great plugin used to get google analytics called [Google Analytics for WordPress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-analytics-for-wordpress/). If that doesn't strike your fancy, you can always use [WordPress.com Stats](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/stats/), which gives you information on where your visitors are coming from, what they're looking at, and what links they click off of your site.

Comment: I need something simpler, I already have Piwik and Analytics (temporary, probably I am going to remove it) for global stats measuring. I need something lighter posts oriented.

Comment: you can get stats for individual posts in google analytics, how come that doesn't work for you?